# how to pass json in a querystring?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to send a JSON to the server by encoding it into the URI using Jquery.param but I get the following error.

```
window.location.href = BriefExportPath+$.param(JSON.stringify({
                        title: $('.ui-dialog-title').text(),
                        items: ko.utils.arrayMap(Neptune.BriefCountrySection.SelectedCountries(), function (item) {
                            return item.ItemName
                        })
                    }))



[CustomAuthorize(Definitions.RoleSonarAdmin)]
        public FileContentResult ExportCsv(string json)
        {
            var x = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            object obj = x.DeserializeObject(json);
            //return File(Helpers.BriefCsvBytes.GetCsvBytes(items), "text/csv", title); 
            return null;
        }



http://dev.neptune.local/Briefs/ExportCsv?0=%7B&1=%22&2=t&3=i&4=t&5=l&6=e&7=%22&8=%3A&9=%22&10=B&11=r&12=i&13=e&14=f&15=+&16=C&17=o&18=u&19=n&20=t&21=r&22=y&23=+&24=L&25=i&26=s&27=t&28=%22&29=%2C&30=%22&31=i&32=t&33=e&34=m&35=s&36=%22&37=%3A&38=%5B&39=%22&40=A&41=f&42=r&43=i&44=c&45=a&46=%22&47=%2C&48=%22&49=A&50=m&51=e&52=r&53=i&54=c&55=a&56=s&57=%22&58=%2C&59=%22&60=A&61=s&62=i&63=a&64=%22&65=%2C&66=%22&67=E&68=u&69=r&70=o&71=p&72=e&73=%22&74=%5D&75=%7D
```

[image]

Comment: are you using -  JSON.stringify(data) - before adding it to the querystring?

Comment: have you tried using HttpUtility.UrlDecode()

Comment: The important line is surely before 579. Where does the `json` variable get assigned?

Comment: It looks like you the querystring parameter name is wrong. From that screenshot it looks like its is '0'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the manual for [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

> Create a serialized representation of an **array or object**, suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request.

You are passing it the return value of `JSON.stringify` which is a **string**.

You need to pass it an object instead.:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(etc etc);
var url = BriefExportPath + $.param( { "json": json } );
location = url;
```

Your server side code will then need to extract the data from the `json` query key.

Comment: I also used  'var oo = xx.Deserialize<MyCustomObject>(json);' instead of the 'DeserializeObject()' so i don;t have to deal with arrays in the code. Just make sure your json property names match your object names. I did ot have to list all the properties, just the ones i wanted filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using this

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    complete: callback
});
```

instead of querystring.

Comment: because im returning a file from the server

Comment: In that case, why not change the contentType to match the kind of file you are returning?

Comment: @TimothyGroote — How would that help if the file was being requested via `.ajax`? And what makes you think the server side code is emitting the wrong content-type anyway?

Comment: `$.ajax` is only different in that it retreives information via an asynchronous process.
You can request file downloads, even with `$.ajax`.

Comment: Also, at the time of comment i had no indication of what kind of file would be returned by the server

Comment: `contentType` only specifies the format of the data being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your server expects the input to end up in a predictable variable name somewhere, yet you seem to try and put it in a GET variable named `0`, as we can see in `ExportCsv?0=`

What your code expects is  `ExportCsv?json=`

Make sure that you are passing the value to the correct GET variable name

Comment: it is being assigned to 0 automatically.

Comment: Then can we at least see the code that is supposed to catch the value of your GET variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```